# select the latest date from joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing problem in join. I am getting duplicate records.Please help me to resolve that..

This is my query:

```
select requestinstanceid from
 requestidt [RIM] 
 inner join requestcdt [RCDT] on [RIM].requestinstanceid = [RCDT].requestinstanceid     
 left join requestcmt [RCMT] on [RCDT].requestcommentid = [RCMT].requestcommentid   
 inner join requestddt [RDDT] on [RDDT].requestinstanceid = [RIM].requestinstanceid   
 left join requestdmt [RDMT] on [RDMT].requestdocumentid = [RDDT].requestdocumentid
```

I am getting result like this:

```
requestinstanceid
184
184
386
389
389
397
```

I should get not get duplicate record and I want to get the latest date from each record.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `FROM` in that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code joins to the 'top 1' of a derived table. You should be able to work out how it could be applied to join to the Top 1 of sub-query sorted by date DESC.

```
SELECT T2.TempEmailID, T1.EmailID
FROM tbl1 T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, RANK() Over (Partition By EmailID Order By TempEmailID DESC) as TopOne FROM tbl2) T2 ON T1.EmailID = T2.EmailID AND TopOne = 1
```

Comment: i am joining multiple table. so it is taking long time to display the result can you help me.

Comment: You need to post some code and sample data - so I can stick it into SSMS and reproduce your issue. If you do that I'll modify your code to return what you want.